# How do I coordinate interactions with multiple impure and asynchronous services in a functional way

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I am trying to teach myself FP but most of the documentation is either absurdly basic (“This is an Option!” “this is an Either!”) or so abstruse I am not completely sure it isn't parody.

Let me give a hypothetical but reasonable situation:

The purpose of the function is provide an endpoint that accepts a file name and a string and write to static store.  The steps are

1. check that the user has few than 10 files stored already; if he has, return false
2. record the name of the file to the database
3. write the file to the files system
4. log the transaction
5. return true

So there are three external system: the database, the file-system, and the logger.  A naïve implementation would be

```
const USER_FILE_MAX = 10;
const saveFile = async (user: User, filename: string, contents: string): boolean => {
  if (await db.fetchFileCount(user) >= USER_FILE_MAX) {
    return false;
  }
  const success = await db.transaction(async () => {
    await db.writeFilename(user, filename);
    await fs.writeFile(filename, contents);
   });
   logger.log(`${user}.name wrote ${filename} ${success? "un" : ""}successfully`);
   return success;
};
```

From an FP point of view, this is terrible -- but I am struggling with how to re-write the function and the services to want to make it functional, easily readable, and testable.

Various sources tell me I should use IO monads, Effects monads, or Tagless-final monads, but I do not see how to do it well in any option.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: `Task` is a monad for async coputations in FP TS but w/o error handling. You can either compose it with `EitherT` transformer or use the predefined specialized monad `TaskEither`. TS is mostly designed with imperative programming in mind and thus has its limitiations regarding FP. FP TS tries to work around this limitations, which quickly gets hacky though. Unfortunately, there is only a rather marginal ecosystem for FP in JS, so the learning material that goes beyond rookie level is rare.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that fp-ts isn't exactly aimed at beginners. Quoting from the official docs: `Teaching functional programming is out of scope of this project, so the documentation assumes you already know what FP is.`

Comment: Having said that, there are a few [learning resources](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/learning-resources/) that might be useful in your case. The one that's probably most relevant to your use case is [interoperability with non functional code](https://dev.to/gcanti/interoperability-with-non-functional-code-using-fp-ts-432e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I would advise to use TaskEither as your monad for network calls (it's basically a lazily-evaluated promise that returns an Either (and thus handles errors and is a Promise that always resolves, never rejects), and for file IO I would use IOEither. fp-ts advises Task and IO as monads for async and sync operations.

```
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/TaskEither'
declare const dbWriteFilename: (user: User, filename: string, t?: Transaction) => TaskEither<SomeDbError, void>
declare const dbFetchFileCount: (user: User, t?: Transaction) => TaskEither<SomeDbError, number>
declare const runInTransaction: <A>(thunk: (t: Transaction) => TaskEither<SomeDbError, A>) => TaskEither<SomeDbError, A>
declare const writeFile: (filename: string, contents: string) => IOEither<SomeFileError, void>

const USER_FILE_MAX = 10;

const saveFile = (user: User, filename: string) => runInTransaction(t => pipe(
  dbFetchFileCount(user, t),
  TE.chain(TE.fromPredicate(count => count < USER_FILE_MAX, () => 'too many files')),
  TE.chain(() => dbWriteFilename(user, filename, t)),
  TE.chainIOEither(() => writeFile(filename, contents))
))()
```

At any point in this "pipe" if a TE fails it will skip any `chain` function and only execute things in `getOrElse` or `mapLeft` type functions that affect the Left type of the TaskEither.

By convention, the Left type of TaskEither represents errors, and Right type represents success values.

Now you don't have to return T/f anymore, you can do something like:

```js
if(Either.isRight(await safeFile(...)()) {
  // success!
}
```

and a fully fleshed example:

```js
pipe(
  saveFile(...),
  TE.fold(
    e => console.error('Whoops!', e),
    () => console.log('Great success!')
  )
)()
```

`fold` takes a TaskEither and returns a Task (in this case it would take a TaskEither<SomeError, void> and return Task (since both functions passed into fold return void).